# First occurrence of a character in string. Regular expression needed

Tags: regex

I have some CSV data like this:

```
1325318514,197.1,184.9,172.4,146.0,147.3,131.1,280.9,182.7,12.6,5.0,0.0,73001,65848,0
1325318536,196.2,184.2,172.1,146.3,147.1,131.1,264.9,175.6,12.6,5.0,0.0,71590,64616,0
1325318557,196.6,184.9,172.1,147.6,146.8,130.9,264.9,178.4,12.6,5.0,0.0,69607,61274,0
1325318578,196.7,184.2,172.1,148.4,146.8,130.6,255.9,174.0,12.5,5.0,0.0,74127,59221,0
....
```

i want to replace the first , with a space on each string but not the rest of the ,s

Any ideas on the regexp for that?  Tried a few different things and just cant seem to get it to work...

Comment: The regular expression for that is just a single comma. The question is how to *use* the regex; and the answer to that question will depend on the programming language you're using. So . . . what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear, I just give an example, hope it is helpful for you:

```
 sed 's/,/ /1' <<<"1325318514,197.1,184.9,172.4,146.0,147.3,131.1,280.9,182.7,12.6,5.0,0.0,73001,65848,0
1325318536,196.2,184.2,172.1,146.3,147.1,131.1,264.9,175.6,12.6,5.0,0.0,71590,64616,0
1325318557,196.6,184.9,172.1,147.6,146.8,130.9,264.9,178.4,12.6,5.0,0.0,69607,61274,0
1325318578,196.7,184.2,172.1,148.4,146.8,130.6,255.9,174.0,12.5,5.0,0.0,74127,59221,0"
```

output:

```
1325318514 197.1,184.9,172.4,146.0,147.3,131.1,280.9,182.7,12.6,5.0,0.0,73001,65848,0
1325318536 196.2,184.2,172.1,146.3,147.1,131.1,264.9,175.6,12.6,5.0,0.0,71590,64616,0
1325318557 196.6,184.9,172.1,147.6,146.8,130.9,264.9,178.4,12.6,5.0,0.0,69607,61274,0
1325318578 196.7,184.2,172.1,148.4,146.8,130.6,255.9,174.0,12.5,5.0,0.0,74127,59221,0
```

Answer (score 0):

In most regex implementations, use the pattern

```
/([^,]*),(.*)/gm
```

And replacement text

```
$1 $2
```